# Как повесить @click на строку в таблице библиотеки vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Как можно повесить обработчик события @click на определенное поле в таблице, если все эти строки записаны в js файле?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>Peek-a-boo!</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Dgacarda/pen/YRpmJY?&editors=101

Comment: вроде бы все работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
<tr @click="onRowClick(props.item)">
  <td @click.stop="onCellClick(props.item)">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
  ...
</tr>

...

methods: {
    onRowClick(item) {
        console.log('Click on row ' + item.name);
    },
    onCellClick(item) {
        console.log('Click on cell ' + item.name);
    }
},
```

Стоит обратить внимание на конструкцию `@click.stop` - она позволяет остановить распространение события, чтобы при клике на указанную ячейку вызывался только обработчик `onCellClick`, без дальнейшего вызова `onRowClick`.